# Is this firebase security rule redundant?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a collection of `users`, and I have a separate collection of `usernames`. In my collection `usernames` I store different usernames as `doc_ids`. That is, under collection `usernames` I can have `doc_ids` as `first`, `second`, `third`, and so on. Under each `doc_id` I store the following info:

```
{
  ownerId: id,
  dateUpdated: someDate
}
```

When I change some user's username, I execute a batch query, where I first delete the `oldUsername` doc, and then insert the `newUsername` doc with the appropriate fields. My question is regarding one of the security rules, related to the `usernames` collection. Do I need to check, if I already have such username (that is such `doc_id`). Do I need the following rule:

```
match /usernames/{username} {
  allow create: if !exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/usernames/$(username))
}
```

I think this rule, is redundant since I am enforcing the uniqueness of collection ids, but I already saw it on a few other posts, so I wanted to check other people's opinions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, that rule does nothing as the `create` will only be triggered when the document doesn't exist yet. If the document already exists, its `.update` will be triggered.

This type of check is common in a `.write`, but not needed when you're using the more granular `.create`.